# Best practices : comment @return for $this->render twig

Tags: symfony

example :

```
return $this->render('interimaire/search.html.twig',['foo'=>$bar]);
```

What is the best practice for comment @return above method ?

```
/**
     * @Route("/foo", name="foo")
     *
     * @param $request Request
     * @return ????????????????????????????????????????????
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('twig.html.twig',['foo'=>'bar']);
    }
```

if I comment : @return Response 
Phpstorm tells me that it's an undefined class

Answer (score 0):

You could either specify the returned type using the class including the namespace, which would be `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` here

```php
/**
 * @Route("/foo", name="foo")
 *
 * @param $request Request
 * @return Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function search(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('twig.html.twig',['foo'=>'bar']);
}
```

or add it as a `use` statement, and simply use `Response` as you already tried.